# It it possible to start two list levels at once in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

This has been driving my insane for years and years and I finally decided to look into it and found no solution.

You know how sometimes you have a multi-level list but nothing to actually put in the main level? 
I mean something like this:

```
1) A. Ipsum Lorem Bla Bla Bla
   B. Yada Yada Yada
   C. Hello World
2) A. Another Ipsum Lorem Bla Bla Bla
   B. Yada Yada Yada
   C. Hello World
```

Best I get with Microsoft Word (unless I do it manually, which would suck) is:

```
1)
   A. Ipsum Lorem Bla Bla Bla
   B. Yada Yada Yada
   C. Hello World
2) 
   A. Another Ipsum Lorem Bla Bla Bla
   B. Yada Yada Yada
   C. Hello World
```

It would seem something elementary to be able to do yet I can't seem to find a way to make it work.
Thanks in advance!

Edit: A 'cheat' I found [here](http://word.tips.net/T008094_Combining_First_and_Second_Numbered_Levels_on_One_Paragraph.html) is to have the sublist start a B. and only manually write in A. It's better than nothing, but weird that word doesn't support this natively.

Comment: How would you indicate the start of the "parent" list item, vs. a child list item?

Comment: Press backspace after enter? Kinda like you do it now, except without having to put an empty line in the main level.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a good way. SOme other things you could do are as follows, but I wouldn't really consider any of them to be an improvement over the "cheat" that you found.

Let's say you are using a multilevel Heading List for your numbering and you are using Heading 1 for "1)" and Heading 2 for "A."

Then if you start your "A." bullet using the field code { LISTNUM \l 2 }, you can format your B. and C. bullets using the Heading 2 style and they should be numbered correctly without having to start the list at 2. (LISTNUM is really intended for numbering within a single paragraph, so in fact you could terminate each para. with a hard line end and add a { LISTNUM \l 2 } to get the next paragraph number, but that's even more effort and loses you paragraph layout flexibility.

IMO to make this stuff look OK you really have to make the two styles look similar to each other anyway, because the first bullet will be formatted with Heading 1 paragraph styling. I don't thin keven the old "Style Separator" helped you there - you would end up with one style's numbering disappearing.

Another possible "improvement" would be to define your multilevel list so that the Heading 1 style's numbering had the literal "A." in it already, and level 2 always started at 2 (i.e. "B.") It would just save you typing that "A." every time. But I doubt that you will have much control over the spacing between the "1)" and the "A." if you do that.

You could also put your text in a two-column table with invisible borders where you used column 1 for the Heading 1 levels and column 2 for the Heading 2 items. It's pretty nasty IMO because of the way things behave differently inside tables and so on, but I suppose it may be appropriate in some cases.